# How do you show elements only when user is either logged in or logged out in Angular 2+?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-routing, angular-observable

I am working on an Angular 2+ app. I am finding it very difficult to implement something that was relatively simple in AngularJS.

I would like my top navigation to show a <kbd>LOG IN</kbd> button when the user is not logged in and a <kbd>LOG OUT</kbd> when she is.

I've been trying all sorts of things but I cannot get it working properly. I want it to work consistently, across the whole app, and regardless of reloading (it stores `isLoggedIn` to `localStorage`)

---

My current implementation is not working at all, but I'll share it here so you can tell me if I'm at least somewhere on the right track.

**top-navigation.component.html**

```
<p class="nav-item my-2 my-lg-0" *ngIf="!isLoggedIn | async"><a class="nav-link" routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active">Login</a></p>
  <p class="nav-item my-2 my-lg-0" *ngIf="isLoggedIn | async"><a class="nav-link" routerLink="//logout" routerLinkActive="active">Logout</a></p>
```

**top-navigation.component.ts**

```
export class TopNavigationComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('topnav') topnav: ElementRef;
  //isLoggedIn: boolean;

  isLoggedIn: Observable<Boolean>;

  constructor( private authService: AuthService, private logger: LoggerService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isLoggedIn = this.authService.getIsLoggedIn();
  }
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  loggedIn$: Subject<Boolean> = new Subject<Boolean>();

  constructor(private logger: LoggerService) {
    let isLoggedInLocalStore = (localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn') === 'true');
    if (!isLoggedInLocalStore) {
      isLoggedInLocalStore = false;
      localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', isLoggedInLocalStore.toString());
    }
  }

  getIsLoggedIn(): Observable<Boolean> {
    //return (localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn') === 'true');
    return this.loggedIn$.asObservable();
  }

  login(): void {
    // TODO
    this.logger.log("AuthService | Login clicked...");
    localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', 'true');
    this.loggedIn$.next(true);
  }

  logout() {
    // TODO
    localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', 'false');
    this.loggedIn$.next(false);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that my answer will help you. For such purposes I created service named GlobalEventsManager.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs/BehaviorSubject";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

@Injectable()
export class GlobalEventsManager {

    private _showMainMenu: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);
    public showMainMenuEmitter: Observable<boolean> = this._showMainMenu.asObservable();

    constructor() {
      this.showMainMenu(Boolean(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')));
    }

    showMainMenu(ifShow: boolean) {
      this._showMainMenu.next(ifShow);
    }


}
```

In this example I show/hide menu depends on user is either logged in or logged out. 
How you can use it(not full code of class, just example) :

```
import { GlobalEventsManager } from "../../core/_helpers/index";
export class ExampleClass implements OnInit {
   constructor(private globalEventsManager: GlobalEventsManager) {

   }

   login(): void {
       //Your code
       ...
       //Show main menu for authentificated users
       this.globalEventsManager.showMainMenu(true)
   }

   logout(): void {
      //Your code 
      ...
      //Hide main menu
      this.globalEventsManager.showMainMenu(false)
   }

}
```

And how can you use it in your component (not full code, just example):

```
import { GlobalEventsManager } from '/_helpers/index';


@Component({
    selector: "main-menu",
    templateUrl: "main-menu.component.html",
})

export class MainMenuComponent  {
    showMainMenu: boolean = false;


    constructor(private globalEventsManager: GlobalEventsManager) {
        this.globalEventsManager.showMainMenuEmitter.subscribe((mode) => {
            // mode will be null the first time it is created, so you need to igonore it when null
            if (mode !== null) {
              this.showMainMenu = mode;
            }
        });
    }

    //Other code 
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

And now you have boolean showMainMenu variable depends on your user.

PS: You also can use this GlobalEventsManager for other purposes. eg. to manage the global events that should affect your application.

PPS: I found similar solution on stackoverflow about 1 year ago. Just I couldn't find the link. And therefore tried to describe the solution here.

Thanks. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the right way but with a little modifications:

In your top-navigation.component.ts:

```
isLoggedIn:boolean;

constructor(private cd:ChangeDetectorRef, private authService: AuthService, private logger: LoggerService ) { 
      this.authService.getIsLoggedIn().subscribe((loggedIn:boolean) => {
      this.isLoggedIn = loggedIn;
      this.cd.markForCheck();}
}
```

And in your auth.service.ts:

```
getIsLoggedIn(): Subject<Boolean> {
    return this.loggedIn$;
}
```

And remove | async from your HTML.

Whenever the user logged in you will send true throw your Subject from the service and all the subscribers will get notified and the same when user logged out.

Answer (score -2):

What you are looking at is a to use a Central [**Shared Service**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) or Even use [**Event Emitters**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/event) for this Purpose.

You will have to use this in combination with Local Storage . When the user logs in you need to save the data in a Shared service and also the Local storage . So this will ensure if he dosent log out you can have all the data in local storage and check if the user is logged in or not.

And when he presses the Logout button Remove the local values from Local Storage and Shared service.

Now how to show the Login and Logout buttons here is where the Event Emitters and Shared Services will shead their magic . Once you add values to a Shared service it will emit an Observable which will be liostened to by the Observing component and In the Observing Component Make use of If and Else to Display the Buttons.

[**Working Example**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/comment)

Comment: I didn't get you on this it shows a login with google. And then you login and then it will have a logout button

Comment: And i guess the answer is above make use of shared services. This was juat something i did for my project and showed it as an example

Comment: The code link is. Also in the example but it's huge you might take a look at it if you want.